# Google Maps JS change of function

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Issue: When I click on the area next to either address (in the div) when the mouse cursor is default, not the pointer, on click it still takes the user to the location on the map. How can I stop this so it only takes the user to that map location if they click on the actual address rather than clicking on an empty area within that div?

Comment: You only want it to go to the address if the user clicks on: 352 Princes Highway Fountain Gate VIC 3805?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got many calls to "myClick(0)" within anchor tags. If you are a little bit more selective about where you put them you should be able to find the appropriate solution. If you only want the address to trigger the map, then wrap it like this:

```
<a href="javascript:myclick(0)">352 Princes Highway Fountain Gate VIC 3805</a>
```

And remove the calls to any other myClick(0) that you don't need.